# The confusion with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I was learning ES6 modules and wanted to understand how this works behind the scenes, that is, say, we have two js files called, file1.js and file2.js.

I have two questions,

**1.How to turn file2 into a module?**

Is it true that if we use export in file2.js then that file will be determined as a module?

**2. What happens when file2.js becomes a module?**

Is it true that file2.js get wrapped inside a function behind the scenes?

I hope you got my point.

Comment: Yes, usage of `export` or `import` declarations forces code to be interpreted as a module. But in general, all code could be a module, it just depends on how you load it.

Comment: "*Is it true that file2.js get wrapped inside a function behind the scenes?*" - No.

Comment: @Bergi, hi, by "all code could be a module, it just depends on how you load it" you meant that even if we do not use import or export in file2.js, file2.js is still determined as module? And by "load it" you meant load by webpack. Did I get your meaning correctly?

Comment: I mean that when you load it with an `import` statement or a `<script type=module>`, then the code will be evaluated as a module. Or when you tell your transpiler or bundler (webpack) that it is a module, they will treat it as a module. If you load it as a normal `<script>`, it will be evaluated as a normal script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to turn file2 into a module?

Load it as one (e.g. by `import`ing it somewhere)

> is it true that if we use export in file2.js then that file will be determined as a module

No, but if you don't export anything that it isn't likely to be a *useful* module (unless it is the entry point for the program).

> is it true that file2.js get wrapped inside a function behind the scenes?

That would be an implementation detail of the module loader (and not something that is worth worrying about if you aren't writing the module loader). I wouldn't expect any module loader (other than those which transpile to ES5) to do that though.